# How to find Mutations for a reverse oriented gene(like pncA) from TB sequencing fasta file using biopython library in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython, dna-sequence, sequencing

To find a mutation like for S104R(from 2288681 to 2289241 for pyrazinamide), we have to first remove '-'(for stripping insertion/deletions if/any present in fasta file), then take reverse complement of it and then look for the particular mutation assigned with the codon number(here is 104). And I have found the answer using basic string functions but wanted more clean and simple if it is possible with biopython library.

Answer (score 0):

So the following code works fine for me:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
sample_file=SeqIO.parse('fasta_file_location', 'fasta') // there are two items in sample_file(reference and patient sequence)

ref=str(sample_file[0].seq).replace('-','')[2288681:2289241].replace('A', 't').replace('T', 'a').replace('C', 'g').replace('G', 'c')[::-1].upper()[(104-1)*3:(104-1)*3+3]
pat=str(sample_file[1].seq).replace('-','')[2288681:2289241].replace('A', 't').replace('T', 'a').replace('C', 'g').replace('G', 'c')[::-1].upper()[(104-1)*3:(104-1)*3+3]

print("ref: ",ref, "pat: ", pat)  // output-> ref: AGC, pat: CGG
```

but the below code is not working for me:

```
ref=sample_file[0].seq.strip("-")[2288681:2289241].reverse_complement()[(104-1)*3:(104-1)*3+3]
pat=sample_file[1].seq.strip("-")[2288681:2289241].reverse_complement()[(104-1)*3:(104-1)*3+3]
```

Its good to have more convenient approach as the latter one uses biopython functions, so please help if you know how to make it better.

Comment: whats the point of not sharing the input fasta fil with us , so that we can play with it (sorry for the rant)

Comment: sample_file is an iterator ,not sure you can use sample_file[0] just consume it into a list first. sample_file_list = [] for i in SeqIO.parse('fasta_file_location', 'fasta'): sample_file_list.append(i) the you can use ref=sample_file_list[0] or [1], try it and tell us , without your input can't try it by myself